# How to define a generic class which extends Number

Tags: java, generics, operators, generic-method

In the method operator += is not defined, how to solve it?

The class contains methods to find min sum, min positive sum, and max product.

```
class Sub<T>{
public <T extends Number> T minSubSum(T[] a){
    T minsum ;
    T thissum = a[0];
    for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
        minsum += a[i];//The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T
    }
    return minsum;
}
```

Comment: class Sub<T extends Number> { }

Comment: You can't really achieve this in this way. You'll have to drop to `double` through `a[i].doubleValue()` for instance. There are a few other hacks described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4192900/276052) but it's not 100%.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ 웃  a) that may be intentional (other methods may be using `T` (probably not, but still) and b) that doesn't solve the issue at hand.